# Polymer - Creating a generic property definition

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Is there a way to define a property when its type isn't known?

```
properties: {
  value: {
   type: Generic
  }
}
```

What would be the best way to do this?

My problem comes from having a value that may be a `String` or `Number`. I'm aware that I can `parseInt()`, but I would then need to detect if that's necessary. Also, when a property is meant to be a string, that string could be `value = '5'`, which makes conditionally applying `parseInt()` tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to define a property of type `Object`.

```
properties: {
  value: Object
}
```

Given the possible values of your property, parsing is unavoidable but can be simple. For example, you could use a regular expression with [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove all non-numeric characters from the input, and convert the result to a `Number`:

```
Number(value.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ''))
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      value: Object,
      numberValue: {
        computed: '_computeValue(value)'
      }
    },
    _computeValue: function(value) {
      // If the value is a string, remove all non-numeric
      // characters and convert the result to a number.
      return typeof value === 'string'
        ? Number(value.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ''))
        : value;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo value="100"></x-foo>
  <x-foo value="value = '5'"></x-foo>
  <x-foo value="foo 2 bar 4 baz 6 qux"></x-foo>
  
  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <div>[[value]] ==> [[numberValue]]</div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[*regex101* explanation](https://regex101.com/r/vh7Ik6/1) of pattern:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll do it that way was just hoping here was something build in.